# MVC - Data back from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My question : If we already have made view -a strongly typed, then why do we need to return model object back from controller post method to view - MVC 4 asp.net ?

For example : I have calculator view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Number One : @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.numberOne)</p>
    <p>Number Two : @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.numberTwo)</p>
        <input type="submit" value ="Addition" name="calculateOperation"  />
           <input type="submit" value ="Subtraction" name="calculateOperation" />
           <input type="submit" value ="Multiplication" name="calculateOperation" />
           <input type="submit" value ="Division" name="calculateOperation" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
         <p>Output     : @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.result)</p>

}
```

and controller :

```
public ActionResult Calculate(Calculator model, string calculateOperation)
{


    if (calculateOperation.Equals("Addition"))
    {
        int[] array = { 1, 12, 5, 26, 7, 14, 3, 7, 2 };
        model.result = model.numberOne + model.numberTwo;
    }
    if (calculateOperation.Equals("Subtraction"))
    {
        model.result = model.numberOne - model.numberTwo;
    }
    if (calculateOperation.Equals("Multiplication"))
    {
        model.result = model.numberOne * model.numberTwo;
    }
    if (calculateOperation.Equals("Division"))
    {
        model.result = model.numberOne / model.numberTwo;
    }


    return View(model);

}
```

If I don't return the model object, I don't get value of model.result.

Looking for a valid reason.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't have to send back a model, you could just use the [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) parameter, but then you would have to fetch the values and cast them to the correct type your self.

```
public ActionResult Calculate(FormCollection form, string calculateOperation)
{
    // Need to check if form["numberOne"] is null or empty or do a int.TryParse()
    int numberOne = int.Parse(form["numberOne"]);
}
```

With a strongly typed model you get that for free by the [model binders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) in asp.net mvc. The code looks much cleaner and it's easier to use.

With a model you also get the power of attributes, like [validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) and scaffolding. It's much cleaner and easier to validate most scenarios using a model with validation attributes.

---

In this case you need to send a model to the view simply because the view requires it. That's how it is designed. How would the model or the view know that you have made an calculation if you don't store it somewhere? Of course you could also use ViewBag:

```
ViewBag["result"] = model.numberOne + model.numberTwo;
```

And in your view:

```
<p>Output     :@Html.TextBox("result", (string)ViewBag["result"])</p>
```

Comment: I get it. Model object has its own features. But in my case when I post the data or click Add button - Model object has num1=10 (for ex) and num2=20; now I calculate and set the result property of model object to 30 (10+20). Two scenarios : 1) If I don't pass the object I will get num1 and num2 with their values (10 & 30) but result as blank. 2) But if I pass Model Object , I will get all of the three values num1, num2 and result. Why is there a difference. Same model has num1 and num2 but not result.

Comment: Are you using the same Controller Method for both the GET and POST or do you have another method we're not seeing?

Comment: That is my get method : just returns a view.         [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Calculate()
        {
           // var model = new Calculator();
            return View();
        }
I might have used wrong term "Send" , I actually want to know , why we need to "return" back the model once we set the value.

Comment: does your model default any of its properties?  my guess is that if you just return View(); and the view is strongly typed, it probably uses the default constructor of the model class.  Very odd otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. Hence, when you do work on the server, if you want it to display something on the client, you have to send it back down.  An MVC strongly-typed view is really just an abstraction on top of the rendering engine.

When you "Submit" the form you are just doing an HTTP POST back to your controller action (an http request).

Calling

```
 return View(model)
```

means that you are sending an HTTP response that returns a rendered html page (using your view). In your case you're simply passing in the  model as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I always figured that this was to cover cases when there was some kind of explanation or response type data.

For example.  You submit an address to be added to the database and you have a service which checks the address for correctness.  If it is correct, it gets persisted, otherwise it gets corrected, added to a special field in the original object and sent back for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual requirement for your controllers method to return anything that consumes that or any other model.  As a result you still need to be explicit with what View and the data associated with it that you want to return.

They could add some sort of overload to View that would implicitly assume it should use some ViewModel in the method parameters, but that's non-intuitive and unnecessary.